# How to see the data(primary and backup) on each of the node in the Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite

I have 6 Ignite nodes  and all are connected well to form a cluster. Also, i am giving the backup copies as 2 . Now i have sent 20 data to the cluster to check the partition and data(primary and backup). I can see the count using the cache -a -r command .
Is there a command or way where i can see the actual data in each of the node, where i can see the primary data as well as the backup copies?

Answer (score 2):

You could use cache -scan -c=cacheName 
Entries in  cache: SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON

```
+=============================================================================================================================================+
|     Key Class     | Key |           Value Class           |                                      Value                                      |
+=============================================================================================================================================+
| java.lang.Integer | 1   | o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryObjectImpl | SQL_PUBLIC_PERSON_.. [hash=357088963, NAME=Name1] |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

use help cache to see all cache related commands.

see: https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/command-line-interface

---

You also have the option of turning on SQL: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes

and: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/getting-started

then use JDBC/sql to see entries in your cache.